# How to provide the labels with a set of array elements. flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

In Hslider,we use Labels="[0,1,2]" . How to provide array by giving the array name.
ex:
In AS3 we defined array
arr:Array = new Array[0,1,2,3,4];

In Hslider if I write
Labels="{arr}"

I am not able to see the arr values on the slider.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in MXML, you need to bind the array to the labels property of the HSlider, like so:

```
labels="{arr}"
```

Also, please specify if the `arr` variable is labled `[Bindable]`.

Comment: Hei sorry I did it as labels="{arr}"..
I will change the ques.